# Symfony - JS Enable a disabled field not persisting

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form that contains a drop down and a checkbox. The checkbox controls whether or not the dropdown is "disabled" (grayed out) from the initial rendering of the form. I have JS that when you uncheck the box it enables the field and now allows a user to change the value. That all works.

When you uncheck the box AND change the value in the drop down Symfony only persists the value for the checkbox and ignores the new value in the dropdown. I assume that's because symfony knew the box was disabled when the form was initially rendered and ignores any new values posted from changing that value.

I checked the profiler and it is submitting both the new value for the checkbox (1) and also the new value for the dropdown in the post fields.

The doctrine tab of the profiler only shows the checkbox value being updated but nothing for the new dropdown value.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Hopefully some simple option that tells symfony to update everything whether or not it was initially rendered as a disabled field.

Comment: If the field is disabled in the form originally it wont't have any values bound to it on submit. I would say the easiest approach would be to enable to field in Symfony and then disable it on load with javascript and go from there.

Comment: Great I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use readonly attribute, and use JS or jQuery to change the status of the field. I did this in Symfony 4

```
->add('someInput', TextType::class, array(
    'attr' => array(
        'readonly' => true,
    ),
));
```

then use JS to modify it dynamically based on some value

```
if( someCondition ){    
        $(input).prop('readonly', false).attr('required',true);
    } else{
        $(input).prop('readonly', true).attr('required',false);
    }
```